# E-commerce website design

Tags: php, e-commerce

I'm working on a e-commerce website. This website shall be integrated with a payment-  processor. I have the following orders table.

```
orders(InnoDB)
-----------------------
id int PRIMARY KEY
user_account_id int 
item_id int
price decimal(6,2)
payment_mode ENUM(cash,pg)
payment_status(pending,paid,lost)
order_timestamp Timestamp
```

When the order is placed, payment_status will be '**pending**'. User is redirected to payment-processor.If the payment is authorized, payment_status shall be updated as '**paid**'. If the transaction is lost (or) unauthorized payment_status shall be updated as
'**lost**'. I want to give user 30mins to pay. If he fails to pay within 30mins payment_status shall be updated as **lost** and ordered item will be cancled and available for others to book.

So, How can this be achived? How can I run a script after 30mins to update order as lost (or) should I use a cron-job every 5mins checking for lost transactions?

Comment: i probably use an event schedular http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html

Comment: why not have the response from the payment-processor determine the outcome? Typically an order is left as pending, and you can have a cron run and check for 'stalled' orders. Otherwise payment processor should provide update on status.

Comment: @RPM can we use transactions in event scheduler?

Comment: @ravi most likely. too lazy to look it up right now though. but basically an event scheduler just tells mysql to execute a stored procedure at a specific time

Answer (score 0):

I would have done so, in application store pending transactions info, and with timer after 30mins update database + cron task everу N mins(for reliability)

UPD:
Oops, not noticed php tag. As variant, update payment status before selecting payments by status